# Find an Array inside another larger Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following problem that I tried to solve, but I cannot come with a solution:

Write in a class a method that receives as parameters two arrays of numbers a and b and returns true if the elements of b are found in a **in the order of their appearance** and false otherwise.

If the first string has length 0 the method returns false. If the second string is 0, the method returns true.

The signature of the method is:
 public static boolean contains(int[] a, int[] b)

Ex:

contains({1, **2**, **3**, **4**, 2, 1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}) -> true

contains({**1**, 2, 3, **4**, 2, 1, **3**, 4}, {1, 4, 3}) -> true

contains({1, 2, **3**, 4, 2, 1, **3**, 4}, {3, 3, 2}) -> false

contains({**1**, 2, 3, 4, 2, **1**, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 2}) -> false

contains({1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4}, {}) -> true

contains({}, {1, 2, 3}) -> false

My solution until now:

```
public class TestEA8 {
public static boolean contains(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    boolean result = false;

    if(a.length == 0){
        System.out.println(false);
        return false;
    }else if(b.length ==0){
        System.out.println(true);
        return true;}

    for (i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        for (j=0;j<a.length;j++){
            if (b[i] == a[j]){
                result = true;
                break;
                }
            }
            if(j==a.length){
                result =false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return  result;
    }
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Research hint: you're trying to find whether `b` is a **subsequence** of `a`.

Comment: Seems to me like a case for `Collection.containsAll()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Code will solve your problem:

use a variable temp where it will be the tracking index of first array and moves forward in every check.

```
 public static boolean contains(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    boolean result = false;

    if(a.length == 0){
        System.out.println(false);
        return false;
    }else if(b.length ==0){
        System.out.println(true);
        return true;}

    int count = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for (i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        for (j= temp;j<a.length;j++){
            if (b[i] == a[j]){
                count = count+1;
                temp++;
                break;
            }
            temp++;
        }
    }

    if (count == b.length){
        result = true;
    } else {
        result =false;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    return  result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections.indexOfSubList()` method.

Example:

```
public static boolean contains(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return findArray(a, b) > -1;
}

public static int findArray(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return Collections.indexOfSubList(arrayToList(a), arrayToList(b));
}

public static List<Integer> arrayToList(int[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can walk through the first array, "ticking out" the expected element from the second one when you encounter it. If you reach the end of the second array, return `true`, otherwise `false`:

```
public static boolean contains(int[] a, int[] b) {
  int i=0,j=0;
  while(i<a.length && j<b.length){
    if(a[i]==b[j])
      j++;
    i++;
  }
  return j==b.length;
}
```

Test with the provided example data: https://ideone.com/JRBvkm